# My pagination is not showing in my custom page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a custom page that contains a product list.
But it just show toolbar with wrong counts and no pagination like this picture[image: No pagination and wrong product counts]

**All of my products are showing there.**

I've tried to add this scripts on my xml layout

**1.**

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
          <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
```

**2.** `<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>`

I've put this script too on my index.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well toolbar not work that way in your custom module

you can try below code for that in your phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>// Default way
<?php  
       // Custom Way
    $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();
    //$toolbar->setCollection($this->getChild('catalog_product_list')->getLoadedProductCollection());
    $toolbar->setCollection($YourProductCollection);
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $pager = $layout->createBlock('page/html_pager');
    $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);
    echo $toolbar->toHtml();

?>
```

and block class should extend class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`

ex

```
class Mypackge_Mymodule_Block_Listing extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
```

Comment: Pager is showing now. But the pager is not paging my product list. how to make it relate?

Comment: You have to put custom validation in your collection for that , you can refer this post for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322333/magento-set-limit-on-collection

Answer (score 0):

In Controller file you put below code

```
public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        try
        {
            parent::_prepareLayout();
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
            $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
            $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getCollection()->load();
            return $this;

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and  in index.phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>  <!--Add Paging-->
```